# PHP isn't sending mail

Tags: php

I am building a website using a Linode VPS.

I am using Apache and PHP installed using:

```
apt-get install apache2 php
```

This is the HTML form:

```
  <form action="" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">IP</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ip" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>" disabled>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

This is the PHP attempting to send mail:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
  $email_to = "webmaster@domain.com";
  $email_subject = "Contact Form";

  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $ip = $_POST['ip']; 
  $message = $_POST['message']; 


  $email_message  = "Name: ".$name."\n";
  $email_message .= "Email: ".$email."\n";
  $email_message .= "IP: ".$ip."\n";
  $email_message .= "Message: ".$message."\n";

  $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
             'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
             'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
<div class="panel panel-success">
  <div class="panel-body">
    Message sent.
  </div>
</div>
<?php

}

?>
```

The problem is that no e-mail is received and no e-mail is marked as spam.

I added PHP error reporting:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

which doesn't report any errors.

Comment: You used the "stfu" operator `@`... it will prevent the mail function from printing errors

Comment: use mail instead @mail.

Comment: also try to comment out //error_reporting(-1);

Comment: @Marc I removed the `@` but it's exactly the same, no e-mail received.

Comment: Can you show us the form you are using to call the script?

Comment: Is the action attribute filled out correctly?

Comment: Yes, "" is same page, or it's what I've always used when the PHP is on the same page anyhow. What would you set it to? It makes no difference whether I use the actual page name `contact.php` or not.

Comment: Close the `if` condition at the end of the script

Answer (score 0):

First you should say which mailer is configurated on your server.
Secoundary i'd check if that mailer and the correct path is indicated in the php.ini config file.
Just a starting point...

Comment: I haven't installed anything other than `apache2` and `php` packages. I thought PHP was capable of sending mail. It needs a third-party mailer?

Comment: Yes, it does need; basically PHP uses the installed mailer (if properly configurated both the mailer AND php.ini file).

Comment: In my opinion your checklist would be:
a) Discovering which mailer you have installed (if i were you i'd choose postfix)
b) Check and fix configuration of mailer to suits your needs (a basic config should be enought for PHP pourpose) in case of postfix a good starting point is: http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html
c) Try to send a mail from your server using the proper command trough SSH (it depends on the mailer)
d) check the mail log file if mail doesn't arrive, and try to understand why
e) if everything goes smooth modify the php.ini file to correctly point the mailer

Comment: I found Postfix very easy to configure, so you might install it and follow the "standard" simple configuration help i linked you. When you'll have successely test a simple mail send from Postfix via SSH... you are almost there!